# Comparing two files using perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 files: A.txt and B.txt. In file A.txt, first filed having number series with 5 digit, in B.txt file whole number is given. If that first 5 digit of File A.txt is not match with second file B.txt, then need to print those numbers in separate file.i.e. numbers in B.txt has to print in another file.

**A.txt**

```
81270,UEDP35
81274,UEDP35
87562,UEDP35
89537,UEDP35
90050,UEDP35
99358,UEDP35
99369,UEDP35
99560,UEDP35
99561,UEDP35
```

**B.txt**

```
8127047667
8756209276
9956176149
8127463873
8953713146
9935805068
9005080751
9956088702
9936916718
```

Comment: I know how to do using grep or shell. but need in perl. someone pls help me

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not rent-a-coder. If you have a specific problem, then ask away, but don't ask people to write an entire script for you.

Comment: Is the comparison position-dependent, or they can be anywhere in the file?

Comment: @thor: I used cat B.txt | egrep -v "|81270|81274|" which filter out the odd number.

Comment: @Quentin: I know, I am sorry for asking this, but really i am in beginning stage of perl. Just learning.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Yes position dependent, if first 5 digits is common then neglect those number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open AIN, "<A.TXT" or die("A.TXT");
open BIN, "<B.TXT" or die("B.TXT");
my %seen;
while (<AIN>) { 
  my $v = (split(/,/))[0]; 
  $seen{$v}++; 
}
while (<BIN>) { 
  my $v=(split)[0]; 
  print "$v\n" if not $seen{substr($v, 0, 5)}; 
}
close AIN;
close BIN;
```

Comment: :Thanks alot..................

Comment: Picking nits in the code: You should check that the open statements succeeded, and it is generally better to use 'lexical file handles': `open my $a_in, '<', 'A.TXT' or die "Failed to open A.TXT ($!)";` (where you can avoid repeating the file name if it in a variable).  But it should work which is what's important.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make loop for this. Give A and B files as input once comparison completed for one loop, again i am trying to give another input files say AA.txt BB.txt.                             ls -1 UEDP* | while read line; do f1=`echo $line | cut -f1 -d'.'`; f2=`ls -1 BB_UEDP* | grep $f1`; ./test.sh $f1 $f2; done. I am getting below error readline() on closed filehandle A at ./test.sh line 7.
readline() on closed filehandle B at ./test.sh line 12. In both input files. UEDP is common word in file